# Conditional Probability Question - Probability on Quiz

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am having trouble with a problem involving conditional probability. The question is as follows:

A student is taking a history quiz, which consists of $6$ multiple choice questions and each multiple choice question has $5$ answer options (and only $1$ of these $5$ answer options are correct). Suppose that the student learned the material asked in question $n$ with probability $p_n$; where $n =1,2, \ldots,6$. If the student learned the material asked in the question, then the student is guaranteed to answer that question. If they did not learn the material in question $n$, then that student guesses the answer to that question at random.

**[a]** What is the probability that the student **learned all of the material** covered on the exam, **if** they got a perfect score.

**[b]** What is the probability that the student got a perfect score 6/6 **and** did not learn any material that was covered on the exam?

**[c]** If $p_n = 1/2$, for all $n =1,2, \ldots,6$, find and simply the answers found in [a] and [b] as much as possible.

---

When beginning the problem, I first defined the following:

**A:** student answered $n$-th question correctly

**B:** student learned the material for $n$-th question

\begin{align*}
P[A|B]& =1;\\
P[A|B^C]& =1/5;
\end{align*} 
where student chooses randomly.

$$P[B]=P_n;$$ where $n = 1,2, \ldots,6$

---

For **part [a]**, I have the following:

P[student learned the material | answered correctly]
\begin{align*}
P[B|A] & = \frac{P[A|B]P[B]}{P[A|B]P[B]+P[A|B^C]P[B^C]}\\
       & = \frac{P_n}{P_n +(1/5)(1-P_n)}
\end{align*}

Now, we assume that material for each question are different. So, each question is independent.

P[Student learned all material | answered all questions correctly]

$$\Pi_{n=1}^6 P[B|A]$$

$$\Pi_{n=1}^6 \frac{(P_n)}{P_n +(1/5)(1-P_n)}$$

For **part [b]**, I have the following:

P[Student did not learn the material for nth question | they answered correctly]

$$=P[B^C\cap A]=P[A|B^C]P[B^C]$$

$$=P[B^C\cap A]=\frac{1}{5}(1-P_n)$$

P[Student did not learn any material | answered question correctly]

$$\Pi_{n=1}^6 \frac{1}{5}(1-P_n)$$

For **part [c]**, I have the following:

[a] Becomes: 
\begin{align*}
\Pi_{n=1}^6 \frac{.5}{.5+.2(1-.5)} & = \left(\frac{.5}{.5+.10}\right)^6\\
& =0.3349
\end{align*}
$$33.49\%$$

[b] Becomes: 
$$\Pi_{n=1}^6 P_n = (\frac{1}{5}(1-P_n))^{6}=0.000001=0.0001\%$$

---

Any help or suggestions for this question and my answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the errors in part b) noted in an answer below, there are algebra errors in the steps that follow. Of course this part of the answer had already gone wrong, but it might help in the future to look at how to be more accurate in transcribing results and how to avoid algebraic errors.

Comment: No need to apologize to **me** for the errors. I just worry that something similar could happen when it matters, for example on a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the question in part b). This is not a conditional probability like in part a). The “**if**” and “**and**” are bold for a reason; part a) asks for a conditional probability whereas part b) asks for the probability of the intersection of two events.

(Also, you seem to have made an error in copying the result for $P[B\mid A]$ from part a) to part b), but that’s not relevant to the actual question in part b).